# How to use output of Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am learning Hive.Suppose I did some analysis by using hive query and also got ouput from it but in real projects,

1.How we give/transfer this output to client

2.Further how client use this output.

Please Guide.

Comment: Like how you do in RDBMS. You store your _output_ in a table. Then, you access that table using `SELECT` or use `JDBC` to use the data in programs or use Reporting tools like Tableau to visualize the data. Seriously, what is your question about?

Comment: Philantrovert really thank you for your reply as I am in initial stage of learning Hadoop please tell me can we integrate reporting tools like Tableau with hadoop/hive and is hive developer expected to work on tableau also or is there separate team for tableau how exactly it works in real projects or what is the project flow(how we get data from client  ,how we process it and finally how client get final result, in short)

Comment: See, all this client-developer relation and it's functions can vary from project-to-project. No, you are not supposed to learn Tableau if you plan on working on Hadoop Ecosystem. Hive is a data warehousing tool which is used to store incredibly large amounts of data and perform batch processing and analytics on it. I suggest you read [Hadoop The Definitive Guide](http://barbie.uta.edu/~jli/Resources/MapReduce&Hadoop/Hadoop%20The%20Definitive%20Guide.pdf). you will be able toget most of your answers here.

Comment: philantrovert thank you for your reply now I got all the basic idea about how it works.Thank You!